# Sparkup doesn't work in vim for me

Tags: vim

I installed sparkup vim plugin, i'm sure it's in the right place. I use archlinux.
And my vimrc: http://wklej.org/id/504484/
Sparkup just doesn't work at all. 
I don't know what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work at all" ? You should give a little bit more information if you expect some help. What did you do ? How do you check it does not work ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Doesn't work means that it doesn't compile something like that: div {test} to <div>test</div> after ctrl+e

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, i found out what was the problem.
First it was python version which needed to be change

```
#!/usr/bin/env python to python2
```

in sparkup.py file

Second, I needed to add

```
filetype plugin on
```

To .vimrc file.

Answer (score 1):

Sparkup needs vim to be compiled with Python 2 -- you can check using `:python print 42` whether it is.

Isn't Arch shipped with Python 3 by default anyway? I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: A better check for Python 2 would be: `:python import sys; print sys.version`

Comment: `:python` is always Python 2. If you want Py3k, you have to go `:python3` so it's good enough for this test case I figure. Or did I oversee something?